# Handling multiple API calls through a Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

We already have a Web API which handles multiples types of calls (it's already deployed into an Azure environment). What we want to achieve is to be able to track each of these calls so we can define further actions in the event of a success/failed call.

We taught of using Logic App to achieve this.

If I look at the available connectors right now, the only thing that seems to come close of what I want to achieve is the Request connector, which would be my trigger.

The thing is that it needs to know the body's JSON schema of the request. Also, it only supports POST requests.

If I look atother existing posts, people seems to suggest to create multiple Logic Apps, one for each type of request. Something that I don't want to do.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: You could design the JSON payload in the body to accept request from multiple functions as it were and have the rest of the JSON body pass the actual data you need to process.

Comment: Yeah I thought of that, but I would to know if there is any other way or other types of connector that would handle such request.

Comment: I don't know of any I'm afraid

Comment: You could use the Azure API-Management service to do this, and you'd get a lot more functionality/features specific to REST APIs as well. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/api-management/